What if I don't want to display the first directory in the find command?
I don't want to display the first directory component of paths printed by the inner find command from the below example
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -exec sh -c '
for dir do
echo "\n\n${dir#.*/}\n"
find "$dir" -exec md5sum {\} +
done' sh {} + >> ../md5

Output example:
dir1

md5sum value ./dir1/file1

dir2

md5sum value ./dir2/dir3/file2

I do not want to display the first directory component i.e ./dir1 and ./dir2 in the ./dir1/file1, ./dir2/dir3/file2 paths, instead I want find to print ./file1 and ./dir3/file2
Is there any way to do that?
Thank you in advance

Please describe your purpose in detail. You want to run md5sum on every file in the current working directory, recursively? If so, you're kinda jumping through hoops, the script could be heavily simplified to just one find command. In general, a combination of find [...] -printf '%P\n' + ${dir#.*/} will likely do the trick. With the usual caveat that filenames with newlines etc etc. But if you describe what you want to do exactly we should be able to help making the script less cumbersome and deal flawlessly with any filename.

You can then cd into each of those directories in a subshell and use find . there:
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -exec sh -c '
  for dir do
    printf "\n\n%s\n\n" "${dir#./}"
    (cd "$dir" && find . -type f -exec md5sum {\} +)
  done' sh {} + >> ../md5

Or in zsh, also sorting the lists and avoiding the ./ prefix:
autoload zargs
for dir (*(ND/)) (
  printf '\n\n%s\n\n' $dir
  (cd -- $dir && zargs -r --eof= -- **/*(ND.) '' md5sum --)
)

With GNU find, the ./ prefix can be avoided by using its -printf '%P\0' combined with xargs -r0 or a loop that reads NUL-delimited records.
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -printf '%P\0' |
  while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do
    printf '\n\n%s\n\n' "$dir"
    (
      cd "./$dir" &&
        find . -type f -printf '%P\0' |
          xargs -r0 md5sum --
    )
  done

(here assuming bash/zsh or recent versions of ksh93 for the read -d '').
